# What's another way of saying, "The problem with that is..."

Tags: business-language

I have a call center rep who constantly tells customers, "The problem with that.." or "Let me tell what the problem with that is."  What would be a more appropriate phrase?

Comment: Hmm. A *good* call center rep would constantly tell customers *The **solution** to that is...*

Answer (score 3):

> A difficulty with that would be...
>
> That would raise the concern that...
>
> One issue with that would be...
>
> A better approach might be... to avoid the possibility of...
>
> We recommend... as we've found this prevents...